# How to set width and height of a svg inside another svg

Tags: html, svg

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
</svg>
```

Like the code above, I set the width and height of the inner svg element, but I find that the width and height of the inner svg element are still 0.

Is there any way to set the width and height of the inner svg element?

Comment: How are you finding that the width and height are 0?

Comment: @RobertLongson I inspect the element in Chrome DevTools

Comment: The bug is in Chrome's DevTools in that case. Raise a bug against the Chromium bugtracker.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I tested in Firefox, and the inner svg has the right width and height.